# How to upload image files in database in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I want to upload image files in a table. So I tried this code for uploading image

```
$fieldset->addField('image', 'file', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('menu')->__('Image'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'image',
      ));
```

This is my controller file for saving data

```
public function saveAction() {
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

            $model = Mage::getModel('menu/menu');
            $model->setData($data)
            ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

            try {

                $model->save();
                $menu_id = $model->getId();
                if(isset($data['links'])){
                    $customers = Mage::helper('adminhtml/js')->decodeGridSerializedInput($data['links']['customers']); //Save the array to your database

                    $collection = Mage::getModel('menu/grid')->getCollection();
                    $collection->addFieldToFilter('menu_id',$menu_id);
                    foreach($collection as $obj){
                        $obj->delete();
                    }
                    foreach($customers as $key => $value){
                        $model2 = Mage::getModel('menu/grid');
                        $model2->setMenuId($menu_id);
                        $model2->setCustomerId($key);
                        $model2->setPosition($value['position']);
                        $model2->save();
                    }
                }

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('menu')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);

                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
                    return;
                }
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('menu')->__('Unable to find item to save'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
```

Ignore menu/grid model, my model is menu/menu

But I am not able to upload it. How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: You will require to add image upload code in your controller file. Please share your controller file code

Comment: edited @JaiminSutariya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your field code with below.

```
$fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('menu')->__('Image'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'image',
      ));
```

Use below code in your controller file.

```
public function saveAction() {
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != '') {
                try {
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);                   
                    $newDir = "YOUR_DIRECTORY_TO_UPLOAD";

                    $newdirPath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . "YOUR_DIRECTORY_TO_UPLOAD";

                    if (!file_exists($newdirPath)) {
                        mkdir($newdirPath, 0777);
                    }

                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $newDir . DS;
                    $resizedPath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $newDir;
                    $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['image']['name']);
                    $uploadedimage = $uploader->getUploadedimage();
                    $_imgUrl = $resizedPath . $uploadedimage;

                } catch (Exception $e) {

                }
                $data['image'] = $uploader->getUploadedimage();
            }
        $model = Mage::getModel('menu/menu');
        $model->setData($data)
        ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

        try {

            $model->save();
            $menu_id = $model->getId();
            if(isset($data['links'])){
                $customers = Mage::helper('adminhtml/js')->decodeGridSerializedInput($data['links']['customers']); //Save the array to your database

                $collection = Mage::getModel('menu/grid')->getCollection();
                $collection->addFieldToFilter('menu_id',$menu_id);
                foreach($collection as $obj){
                    $obj->delete();
                }
                foreach($customers as $key => $value){
                    $model2 = Mage::getModel('menu/grid');
                    $model2->setMenuId($menu_id);
                    $model2->setCustomerId($key);
                    $model2->setPosition($value['position']);
                    $model2->save();
                }
            }

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('menu')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);

            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
                return;
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
    }
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('menu')->__('Unable to find item to save'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```